# What are some of the best methods in detecting facial movement using state-of-the-art machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, google-cloud

I am currently working on implementing a lip reading system in Python using machine learning and image processing. Currently, two initial implementations have provided promising results, albeit not perfect: the LipNet model and the Google Cloud AutoML Vision API. Before I dive head on into these two different systems, I was wondering if anyone on here had been exposed to any other alternatives for lip reading or any other facial detection issue, and their experiences with these models.

Any information will be greatly appreciated.